# How to fix app keeps downloading the wrong image?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm building a simple image listing app with some extra features, including a download image feature.

I've managed to successfully download the image, but somehow the app keeps downloading the wrong one from my JSON.

Rendering items from a JSON:

```js
renderItem = ({ item }) => {

  imageToDownload = item.image;

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 15, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
      <Card elevation={1}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            alignItems: "flex-start"
          }}
        >

          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                imageToDownload = item.image;
                this.toggleModal();
                this.setState({
                  webViewurl: item.image
                });
              }}
              onLongPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.image)}
              activeColor="blue"
            >
              <ImageBackground
                source={{ uri: item.image }}
                style={{ height: 216 }}
              >
                <IconButton
                  icon="favorite-border"
                  size={20}
                  color="#6200EE"
                  style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
                  onPress={this._savedAlert}
                />
              </ImageBackground>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The download image function:

```js
downloadImage() {
  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}memebook_meme.png`;
  FileSystem
    .downloadAsync(imageToDownload, fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
    })

  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(fileUri, 'photo');
}
```

The download button:

```js
<Button
  icon="file-download"
  mode="contained"
  onPress={this.downloadImage}
  style={{ borderRadius: 0, width: "33.4%" }}
/>
```

**UPDATE**

My data:

```
{
    "listings": [
     {
         "title": "pikachu",
         "image": "https://3.pik.vn/20182c2771b3-e6fd-4018-ba30-ad1d6a1e93ab.jpg"
     }, 
     {
         ...
     }
]
}
```

Comment: Hope this might get to solve your problem https://medium.com/react-native-training/caching-images-in-react-native-709fd94b3e71

Comment: It's helpful and I'll check it out later, thanks, but that doesnt really help with my current situation

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `imageToDownload` inside the `renderItem` so it will be overwritten with every call of `renderItem` and `downloadImage` is using this global variable. Please consider not using global variables as they lead to problems like this.

Make sure to provide the correct value to the download button so that the correct image will be downloaded!

Answer (score 0):

Insert the `download button` into the `renderItem` function and use it.

```js
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
...
<Button
  icon="file-download"
  mode="contained"
  onPress={ (item) => this.downloadImage(item)}
  style={{ borderRadius: 0, width: "33.4%" }}
/>

...
downloadImage(item) {
  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}memebook_meme.png`;
  FileSystem
    .downloadAsync(item.image, fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => {
      console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
    })

  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(fileUri, 'photo');
}
```

Comment: Are you still downloading another file?

Comment: yes, it still downloading random images from my JSON instead of the image I clicked on

Comment: Show me your data.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I've updated my post, check the data example above

Comment: @qhtn There's another JSON Array in JSON. You can try `item.listings.image`